# Why I'm I getting the no matches found error when there is a match?

Tags: zsh, wildcards

```
centos@ip-10-0-5-4 ~ $ sudo ls -l /var/solr/data/new_core/_default/*
zsh: no matches found: /var/solr/data/new_core/_default/*
centos@ip-10-0-5-4 ~ $ sudo ls -l /var/solr/data/new_core/_default/ 
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Mar 28 07:34 conf
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `*` is expanded by the shell before `sudo` is invoked.  If you don't have access to that directory, the `zsh` shell will complain with "no matches found".  If the `NOMATCH` shell option is unset in the `zsh` shell, the shell would have left the pattern unexpanded and `ls` would instead generate a "no such file or directory" error (unless there was something with the literal name `*` in that directory). With `NOMATCH` set, which it is by default, `sudo ls` would not even be invoked.

You may do this instead:

```
sudo sh -c 'ls -l /var/solr/data/new_core/_default/*'
```

This prevents the current shell from expanding the `*` and instead invokes `sh` with the command line that you want to execute as root.

Answer (score 1):

In first case :

1. access right prevent shell(*) expansion of `/var/solr/data/new_core/_default/*` when your are `centos`.
2. <s>command expand then as `/var/solr/data/new_core/_default/*` in first case.</s>
3. <s>there is no `*` file or dir in `/var/solr/data/new_core/_default/`, hence the `no match found`.</s>

In second case, ls find file and list them.

(*) this is the `Filename Expansion` from zsh expansion (see `man zshexpn`).

> FILENAME GENERATION
>
> If  a  word  contains an unquoted instance of one of the characters `*', ...
>
> The word is replaced with a list of sorted filenames that match the pattern.

as you are `centos` before `sudo` zsh could not access dir (e.g. file `conf` ), hence the `no match found`.

Comment: no, same as as @Kusalananda, the error is output by zsh here, not `ls`. `sudo` and `ls` are not run here. They would  be with that one `*` file if using `bash` without the `failglob` option or most other Bourne-like shells (a behaviour that can be considered as a bug).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas edited. Yet, in both case (bash or zsh) the non -expansion of `*` is cause of problème.

Comment: Note that if there was a file called `*` in that directory, with Bourne/ksh/`bash` (without `failglob`), you wouldn't get an error and you would be mislead into thinking that it's the only file there. See also [Why is nullglob not default?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803)